# How to have a POST request on redirected servers?

Tags: php, nginx, server, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting up a nginx load balancer on a script.
www.loadbalancer.com/request.php =>
www.example01.com/request.php
www.example02.com/request.php
www.example03.com/request.php

**eg.** I want to send a POST request and when I go check access_log of `www.example.com` it shows POST but when I go on www.example01.com it shows GET so it don't use my x-www-form-urlencoded.

I'm on nginx/1.10.3.

**www.loadbalancer.com** : `[date] "POST /request.php HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" PostmanRuntime/7.4.0`
**www.example01.com** : `[date] "GET /request.php HTTP/1.1" 200 45 "https://www.loadbalancer.com/request.php" PostmanRuntime/7.4.0`

**loadbalancer.conf**

```
location = /request.php {<br>
  proxy_pass http://backup_servers$request_uri;<br>
  proxy_redirect http://backup_servers$request_uri https://backup_servers$request_uri;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;<br>
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;<br>
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;<br>

  proxy_method POST;<br>

  proxy_set_header content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";<br>
}
```

I expect that the method become POST.

Comment: It doesn't become a POST if the form is submitting to the non-secure http url. A redirect happens from the non-secure http url to the secure https url. Can you confirm the access log when the form submits to a secure https url

Comment: Why it is using port 80 to send the post request? When I set disable return 301 on target server, I have 404 error because nothing is configured everything is on 443 port.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **proxy_pass** and **proxy_redirect** to be **https://** urls. Otherwise you will lose your POST information during the extra redirect. Proxy redirect will use the http location before the https one you specified as well meaning it will always try the http one first.